# embed a presentation into a document using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Is it possible to embed a google presentation into a google document using html or script?  If so can you point me in the right direction as I know nothing about script of html codes.

Answer (score 0):

Not at present. Neither the Google Drive API nor Google Apps Script provide access to presentations.

Visit [Issue 1573](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1573) and star it to receive updates.